# Skype For Business not showing HTML in conversations on Android

Tags: android, html, ios, ucma

I've got the bot application set up to send certain messages as text/html and some as text/plain.  Only the text/plain messages are displayed by the mobile phone SfB client application, but both types are displayed by the SfB desktop client.  I'm wondering if the issue is with the type of client receiving the message or if there is a setting somewhere in SfB Server that needs to be modified so that text/html can be displayed on mobile phones.

Comment: Try adding the `Android` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some research on this issue, and it seems the mobile client only accepts plain text. Even if you send a multipart/alternative package with both text/plain and text/html versions of the message, it will not display on mobile clients. I encountered this while developing a UCMA application. My solution was to use the user agent header for the call to determine if the user was calling from a PC or not, and to convert any HTML to plain text before sending if they were not calling from a PC.

Comment: FYI, the IOS and newest Mac clients (The older Lync Mac client works fine...) also share this limitation, and I've seen similar issues trying to send messages to the Teams client as well